# Rails action controller routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I try to add an administration area to my website. So I added a namespace that contains the controllers "posts" and "category".
In the routes.rb file, I added

```
namespace :admin do
 resources :posts , :categories
 match '/' => 'posts#index', :via => :get
end
```

but with the url:

> myurl.com/admin

i have error:

> No route matches {:controller=>"admin/site", :action=>"home", :locale=>:fr}

It seems that another route is called and overwrites the one I added

but in rake routes i have:

> admin GET    /admin(.:format) admin/posts#index

Here the complete rake routes:

```
    faq GET    (/:locale)/faq(.:format)                    site#faq {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
              rules GET    (/:locale)/rules(.:format)                  site#rules {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
     advanced_rules GET    (/:locale)/advanced_rules(.:format)         site#advanced_rules {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
           play_now GET    (/:locale)/play_now(.:format)               play#play {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
               play GET    (/:locale)/play(.:format)                   site#play {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
               home GET    (/:locale)/home(.:format)                   site#home {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
                    GET    (/:locale)/qrcode(/:code)(.:format)         site#qrcode {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
    forgot_password GET    (/:locale)/forgot_password/:id(.:format)    passwords#forgot_password {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
   android_redirect GET    (/:locale)/android_redirect(.:format)       android#index {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
 general_conditions GET    (/:locale)/general_conditions(.:format)     site#general_conditions {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
            support GET    (/:locale)/support(.:format)                site#support {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
                    GET    (/:locale)/invitation(/:source)(.:format)   invitation#redirection {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
      release_notes GET    (/:locale)/release_notes(.:format)          site#release_notes {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
       release_note GET    (/:locale)/release_notes/:version(.:format) release_notes#show {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
               root GET    /(:locale)(.:format)                        site#home {:locale=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}/}
        admin_posts GET    /admin/posts(.:format)                      admin/posts#index
                    POST   /admin/posts(.:format)                      admin/posts#create
     new_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/new(.:format)                  admin/posts#new
    edit_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id/edit(.:format)             admin/posts#edit
         admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)                  admin/posts#show
                    PUT    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)                  admin/posts#update
                    DELETE /admin/posts/:id(.:format)                  admin/posts#destroy
   admin_categories GET    /admin/categories(.:format)                 admin/categories#index
                    POST   /admin/categories(.:format)                 admin/categories#create
 new_admin_category GET    /admin/categories/new(.:format)             admin/categories#new
edit_admin_category GET    /admin/categories/:id/edit(.:format)        admin/categories#edit
     admin_category GET    /admin/categories/:id(.:format)             admin/categories#show
                    PUT    /admin/categories/:id(.:format)             admin/categories#update
                    DELETE /admin/categories/:id(.:format)             admin/categories#destroy
              admin GET    /admin(.:format)                            admin/posts#index
          completed GET    /payment_completed(.:format)                payment#completed
            android GET    /android(.:format)                          hockeyapps#android
              login POST   /login(.:format)                            registrations#login
      loginfacebook POST   /loginfacebook(.:format)                    registrations#loginfacebook
             status GET    /status(.:format)                           registrations#status
             logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                           registrations#logout
             geturl POST   /geturl/:id/:token(.:format)                paypals#geturl
          getstatus POST   /getstatus/:id/:token(.:format)             paypals#getstatus
  payment_completed GET    /payment_completed(.:format)                payment#completed
    forgot_password GET    /forgot_password/:id(.:format)              passwords#forgot_password
      send_password POST   /send_password(.:format)                    passwords#send_password
```

Here the complete file routes.rb:

```
  scope "(:locale)", :constraints => {:locale => /[a-zA-Z]{2}/} do

    match '/faq' => 'site#faq', :via => :get

    match '/rules' => 'site#rules', :via => :get

    match '/advanced_rules' => 'site#advanced_rules', :via => :get

    match '/play_now' => 'play#play', :via => :get
    match '/play' => 'site#play', :via => :get

    match '/home' => 'site#home', :via => :get
    match '/qrcode/(:code)' => 'site#qrcode', :via => :get

    match '/forgot_password/:id' => 'passwords#forgot_password', :via => :get, :as => "forgot_password"
    match '/android_redirect' => 'android#index', :via => :get, :as => "android_redirect"

    match '/general_conditions' => "site#general_conditions", :via => :get

    match '/support' => "site#support", :via => :get

    match '/invitation/(:source)' => 'invitation#redirection', :via => :get

    match '/release_notes' => 'site#release_notes', :via => :get, :as => "release_notes"
    match '/release_notes/:version' => 'release_notes#show', :via => :get, :as => "release_note"

    root :to => 'site#home', :via => :get
  end

  namespace :admin do
    resources :posts , :categories
    match '/' => 'posts#index', :via => :get
  end

  get 'payment_completed' => 'payment#completed', :as => "completed"

  get 'android' => 'hockeyapps#android', :as => 'android'


  post 'login' => 'registrations#login', :as => 'login'
  post 'loginfacebook' => 'registrations#loginfacebook', :as => 'loginfacebook'
  get 'status' => 'registrations#status', :as => 'status'
  delete 'logout' => 'registrations#logout', :as => 'logout'

  post 'geturl/:id/:token' => 'paypals#geturl', :as => 'geturl'
  post 'getstatus/:id/:token' => 'paypals#getstatus', :as => 'getstatus'

  get 'payment_completed' => 'payment#completed', :as => 'payment_completed'

  #scope :protocol => 'https://', :constraints => { :protocol => 'https://' } do
  #  resources :passwords
  #end
  get 'forgot_password/:id' => 'passwords#forgot_password', :as => 'forgot_password'
  post 'send_password' => 'passwords#send_password', :as => 'send_password'
end
```

Any idea about the problem ?

thanks

Comment: can you give the `path` that you are using which gives this `No route error`

Comment: @JSWorld i'm using  myurl.com/admin

Comment: Use "rake routes" command and check this url will show

Comment: @visnu i show it on the post

Answer (score 1):

`match '/'` is handled by the `root :to => ...` and namespaced. So routing tries to call `site#home` in module (namespace) `admin`.

Try to put the namespace part in front of the `root :to` or match '/admin' separately before defining `root`

Comment: +1, `domain.com/admin` read as `domain.com/(:locale)` if `root :to` before `namespace :admin`

Comment: yes but the error is the same, even if I set the namespace before

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
namespace :admin do
 resources :posts , :categories
 get '', to: 'posts#index', as: '/'
end

scope "(:locale)", :constraints => {:locale => /[a-zA-Z]{2}/} do
 ...
  root :to => 'site#home', :via => :get
 ...
end
```

Output of `rake routes`

```
 admin GET    /admin(.:format)                 admin/posts#index
```

Tried with get `localhost:3000/admin`

```
Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-11 17:41:40 +0700
Processing by Admin::PostsController#index as HTML
  Rendered admin/posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1095ms (Views: 1095.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Indeed, it seems that I have the right road in rake routes. However, the error message is always the same.

Comment: @user1643422 : have you try solution from @Martin M ? I think his solution works. Try `namespace :admin` before `scope "(:locale)"`

Comment: @user1643422 yep, i tried this solution, but no effect on error :s

Comment: have you try get other url, e.g : `domain.com/admin/posts` ? have you get error message?

Comment: @user1643422 can you post your `posts_controller.rb` and `sites_controller.rb` ?
 I think your error cause your app has switched to `locale fr`.